# Test For Convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence, divergent-series

$$
\sum_{k = 1}^\infty \left(\frac{\mathrm{e}^{2\sqrt{k}}}{\mathrm{e}^\sqrt{k}+9}\right)^{2k}
$$

Comment: Is the series summed over the variable $k$?

Comment: yes it is. The first root test is obvious but I am having difficulty to test if the result of the root test is smaller or bigger than 1.

Comment: Does the sum start from $k = 0$ or $k = 1$?

Comment: It is not specified. It is just a sum symbol which I suppose means the infinite sum. The lower bound shouldn't be too important.

Comment: @HerngYi I corrected the code thank you! Seems like the root test wouldn't work since the result after taking the test would be 1 which is inconclusive. Any suggestions?

Comment: @BabakSorouh, seems like the root test isn't going to work since  the result after taking the test would be 1 which is inconclusive. could you please elaborate on the comparison test you mentioned?

Comment: @OmidMoj: I removed the comment, cause the summation was changed. ;-)

Comment: The function goes to $0$ **very** rapidly. Almost nothing is needed. Edit: Well, have to use past tense, we have a function that varies with time.

Comment: @BabakSorouh, any other suggestions this is the last question in a very very long set I'd really appreciate if you could help me! :D

Comment: @AndréNicolas, I still need some sort of convergence test :/

Comment: How can I tell, the function keeps changing. Right now there is trivial divergence.

Comment: This is the correct function. I see no way to use the root test, the only other test that I know is the direct comparison in this case. Do you know what function I could use?

Comment: @OmidMoj: You mean that the **whole thing**, both top and bottom, is raised to the $2k$-th power? Then the $k$-th term $a_k$ blows up, trivial divergence.

Answer (score 2):

In its current form, you do not even need to use tests. Note that for $k\to\infty$, we have that $e^{2\sqrt{k}}/\left(e^{\sqrt{k}}+9\right)\to\infty$, which even more so means that

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\left(\frac{e^{2\sqrt{k}}}{e^{\sqrt{k}}+9}\right)^{2k}=\infty$$

Since the general term of your series does not tend to $0$, your series does not fulfill the necessary conditions for convergence. Hence, it diverges.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** The first part deals with the sequence as it once appeared to be. The remark at the end deals with the sequence as it is at this moment. For that, there is obvious divergence. One should always first ask oneself how a sequence behaves, not what test to use.

**Old:** We make an assumption about the $a_k$ for which we are studying $\sum a_k$. At one stage this **was** the series.

Let us suppose that what is intended is
$$a_k=\frac{e^{2\sqrt{k}}}{(e^{\sqrt{k}}+9)^{2k}  }.$$
Then $a_k$ is less than the term we get by dropping the $9$, so
$$a_k\lt \frac{1}{e^{\sqrt{k}(2k-2)}}.$$
The bottom is, for $k\gt 1$, bigger than $e^{k\sqrt{k}}$
But 
$$\sum \frac{1}{e^{k\sqrt{k}}}$$
converges, by comparison with the geometric series $\sum \frac{1}{e^k}$. Lots of slack.

**Remark:** If instead 
$$a_k =\left(\frac{e^{2\sqrt{k}}}{e^{\sqrt{k}}+9  }  \right)^{2k},$$
as it currently looks like, then note that almost immediately we have $a_k\gt 1$, so, as pointed out in a comment, there is automatic divergence.

By the way, for this version of the series the Root Test works easily. But it is not the best way to approach the problem.